# Research paper on living in areas with fresh air after living for more than 20 years in polluted area and impact on health

Tags: research, lungs, lasting-effects-duration, air-quality, environmental-conditions

Are there any reasearch paper which shows impact on health for the person which is moving from the city with high air pollution to the areas with more fresh air (like countryside)?

Below are 2 main questions which I would like to know from the paper :

Can if affect health negatively/positively?
Can our body get used to the polluted air and can such drastic change have negative impact on one's health?